# Method getting mocked but Value not correctly returned

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, powermock, easymock

I am trying to unit test my class
which is looks something like:-

```
   class A{
       private void method1(){
          B b=new B();
          C c=b.method2();
          if(c!=null){
             ...
             ...
          }
       }
}
```

I want to mock "method2()" inside Class B.
I know that we need to have a mock object of B() so that whenever we call a method on it mocking happens.
This is what I have tried

```
A aMock=Easymock.createNiceMock(A.class);
B bMock=Easymock.createNiceMock(B.class);
Powermock.expectNew(B.class).andReturn(bMock).anyTimes();
Easymock.expect(bMock.method2()).andReturn(new C()).anyTimes();
//have done all the replays and verifies
```

and call it using `aMock.method1()`,
now the main problem is method2is getting mocked( i.e body of method2() is not getting executed)but I am not able to receive object of C as response from this.

My test scenario is:-

I want to test method1() of Class A which in turn calls method2() of class B ,but I dont want it to execute its code(of method2()) and as it is a DB call and I also need the Object of C that is returned by method2() so I am using mocking to achieve this.

Comment: Well what *is* happening? What do you mean by "I am not able to receive object of C"?

Comment: expected behaviour is that mocking should return new object of type C(as I have written ".andReturns(new C()))" instead it is returning a null

Comment: Right, that isn't clear at all in the question - please edit it to make it clearer. Also, please show any attributes specified for your test, and tell us more about how your tests are being run. (JUnit 4? Something else?)

Comment: Edited the question! added my test scenario

Comment: That doesn't show us any annotations for the test, or how you're running the tests. Ideally, show a short but *complete* example of the problem. (It doesn't need to do any database calls... just have a class B with a method which prints "This should not be printed" for example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test `method1()` of Class `A`, then you should not be creating a mock of `A`. Which means you should not be doing `A aMock=Easymock.createNiceMock(A.class);`

For your test scenario, the test would be something like:

```
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class ATest {

    A testableA = new A();

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() throws Exception {
        B bMock = EasyMock.createNiceMock(B.class);
        PowerMock.expectNew(B.class).andReturn(bMock).anyTimes();
        EasyMock.expect(bMock.method2()).andReturn(new C()).anyTimes();
        PowerMock.replay(B.class);
        EasyMock.replay(bMock);

        testableA.method1();

        //assert and validate your scenario here
    }
}
```

You can follow the documentation [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor).

Comment: with this approach if I need to mock some other methods of A they wont get mocked

Comment: The above should suffice the test scenario you mentioned in your question. Do you have additional requirements? Can you give details in code?

Comment: @Vihar1903 For the additional scenario, you can additional use partial mocking provided by mockito. That would fit in nicely with the test case above. Details here: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPartial